# Application build on Xcode 2.4 with mac 10.5 sdk is not getting invoked in Mac 10.3.9?

Tags: objective-c

I have build an application with xcode 2.4 (universal binary with sdk10.5) on Mac 10.6, when im invoking the application in mac 10.3.9 the application is not getting invoked.
Its workin in 10.4 and above version?

Can someone suggest me on this..

Answer (score 3):

The Mac OS X 10.5 SDK targets the Mac OS X system version 10.5. It's no surprise it's not working with earlier versions.

Use the Mac OS X 10.3 SDK if you want your program to run on Panther. I believe it is still available as an optional package when you install Xcode.

Comment: Im getting the following error when im trying to build using sdk10.3
1) error:#error "This header only support _MWERKS_" in stdbool.h and stdarg.h and float.h files and


2)syntax error before va_list in CFString.h and NSString.h files

Comment: A SDK is not just a magical package. They're the complete framework against which you build your program, and newer ones define new symbols. If you try to compile a program built for a certain SDK against an earlier SDK, chances are you are using symbols that are not defined in the earliest one. At any rate, the error messages you gave are insufficient for us to help you. You should start a new question and include the lines that emit the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i loaded the libraries dynamically which i was using and getting the function pointers of the required function, now the build is working fine in 10.3.9??? i need not change the sdk's to make the application run in 10.3.9..

i used dlopen('); and dlsym().

Thanks You.